Hollywood Command terminal colour issue
Before my terminal's hostname colour can change its colour accordiing to the color theme which I set. But then I ran the hollywood command. After its execution, I couldn't change my terminal's hostname colour.

Did you run exit to exit out?

I run Ctrl+C to cancel the operation

Yes. Then after you press CTRL+C, try running exit to see if that returns your terminal to normal.

Most likley byobu is the reason for the color change. Just run:
sudo apt remove hollywood
sudo apt remove byobu

Now you are free to change colors again.
